# Convexity of non separable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

Consider the function $\phi:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$ which is convex and non decreasing. Also let $\ell_i:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$ be convex and non decreasing for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote a collection of $p$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. For $x\in \mathbb{R}_+^p$ and consider the function $f(x)\equiv\sum_{S\in \mathcal{S}} x_S \phi(\sum_{i\in S} \ell_i(\sum_{S'\ni i} x_{S'}))$.

It can be shown that the convexity holds if the vector function $\{\phi_S(x)\equiv\phi(\sum_{i\in S} \ell_i(\sum_{S'\ni i} x_{S'}))\}_{S\in\mathcal{S}} $ is monotone.

Under which condition does the monotone property hold? More generally when is $f(x)$ convex?

Comment: What does $\sum_{S'\ni i} x_{S'}$ mean? And what do $x_S$ and $x_{S'}$ mean?

Comment: There are $p$ sets in $\mathcal{S}$ and each set represents one coordinate of the vector $x$. So $x_S$ is the coordinate corresponding to the set $S$. Similar notation holds for $S'$. And ${S'\ni i}$ means sets that contain the element $i$.

Comment: I think your notation is equivalent to the following:  Define $x =(x_1, ..., x_p) \in \mathbb{R}_+^p$. For each  $i \in \{1, ..., p\}$ let $A_i$ be a fixed subset of indices in $\{1, ..., p\}$.  Then for each $n \in \{1, ..., p\}$ we define: 
$$ \phi_n(x) = \phi \left(\sum_{i \in A_n} l_i\left(\sum_{k : i \in A_k} x_k\right)\right)$$ Since $\phi$ is nondecreasing and the $l_i$ functions are nondecreasing, the resulting functions $\phi_n(x)$ are nondecreasing in the vector $x$ for all $n \in \{1, ..., p\}$.

Comment: The notation is indeed equivalent. However, I do not understand the meaning of 'non-decreasing in $x$'. Do you mean $x_{i}\geq y_{i}$, for all $A_i$, implies $\phi_n(x)\geq\phi_n(y)$? In that case, the assertion is correct and not hard to see. But I am interested in the convexity of  $\sum_{i} x_{i} \phi_i(x)$. If you see a connection between these two things please elaborate.

Comment: Your question asked whether or not the $\phi_n(x)$ functions are "monotone."  Functions that are entrywise nondecreasing are "monotone."

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I should have metioned the definition of `monotone vector function'. The vector function $\mathbf{\phi}(x)$  is monotone iff $\langle x-y, \mathbf{phi}(x)-\mathbf{phi}(y)\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^p$.